# PHP MS SQL populating a drop down menu

Tags: php, sql-server

Dumb noobie question, again.....sorry people:

I'm trying to create a simple drop down menu in PHP, pulling the options from a SQL Server select statement. I'm actually following an example in a book, to learn PHP, and I'm failing.

Here is my code - can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

```
    <?php 

        $sql = "  SELECT 1 AS [ID], 'A' AS [author]
                     ";

        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);

        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) 
        {
            $authors[] = array('id' => $row[0], 'author' => $row[1] ); //these are the column numbers
        }
    ?>

    <label for="author">By author:</label>

    <select>
        <?php foreach ($authors as $author): ?>
            <option value="<?php htmlout($author['id']); ?>">
                <?php htmlout($author['author']); ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

As a result I'm just getting a tiny drop down menu box, with a label, and no options.

The connection to the SQL Server is working...that much I know.

I have echoed the data, and it is returning correctly.

Update: I updated the code above as I made a typo originally, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The coonection works, but are you sure the result of the query is what you expect? Try to just `echo` it and see. I see that you define your query `$sqlsearch` but never use it, so I guess the problem is here:  `$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);` but should be `$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sqlsearch);`

Comment: `$sqlsearch` !== `$sql`. Voting to close due to typo

Comment: hummm...indeed I did make a typo, but unfortunately fixing it didn't fix the code. Thanks to both of you, @Valentino